# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=5.5.0.0

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012

I just installed WCF Data Services Server 5.5.0 on my VS Projects, one using a console application and one using a sharepoint viual webpart project. However, I am getting an error when I add the web part in my SharePoint page and this is the error that I get:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=5.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

in VS I am pointing to the correct directory where the dll is stored and the option Copy Local is true. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by installing WCF Data Services 5.6.0. 
Download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39373)

Follow these steps:

```
1) Close all instances of VS
2) Install the exe
3) Test your Service (Normally I would get the error above at this step)
4) Close VS again and go to your exe and run it again
5) this time click on **Repair** button and that should solve your issue
```